# Get the sum after a linq join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using this linq query to get a list of doubles. The list looks correct, but now I need to total the doubles in the list.

```
        var total = from sauId in schools
                                    join item in entities.AmountTable
                                    on sauId equals item.sauId
                                    select item.amount;
```

Comment: If you want the sum only, why joining with schools ?
    var total = entities.AmountTable.Sum(p => p.amount)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Sum()` on the result:

```
   var total = (from sauId in schools
               join item in entities.AmountTable
               on sauId equals item.sauId
               select item.amount).Sum();
```

If `item.amount` is a `double`, then `total` is also a `double`.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to enclose the entire query within the Sum parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for fluent syntax, I *believe* this would be the way to do it:

```
var total = schools
   .Join(
      entities.AmountTable,
      s => s.sauId,
      at => at.sauId,
      (s, at) => at.amount)
   .Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to group data by its `sauId`:

```
var qry = from item in entities.AmountTable
         group item by item.sauId into grp
         select new {
             sauId = grp.Key,
             amuont = grp.Sum(c=>c.amount)
         };
```